# Google AccountManager Android

Tags: android, accountmanager

I've been trying to figure out how to use the Google account manager to simply provide a way for users to Login to my app.

I have the AuthToken returning, but how can I get some unique info on the account that won't change for example a uniqueID or something so that I can use it to login the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Account` object you get from `AccountManager` has a `name` field which is the user's email address. This should be unique since they are all managed by Google and require a password to set up.

Depending on what permissions you asked for when getting the AuthToken, you can query the endpoint `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=YourTokenHere` and get back a bunch of information about the account.

The response will look something like this:

```
{
 "id": "1234567890",
 "email": "joseph.mother@gmail.com",
 "verified_email": true,
 "name": "Joe Mama",
 "given_name": "Joe",
 "family_name": "Mama",
 "link": "https://plus.google.com/1234567890",
 "picture": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-abcd/abcd/abcd/1234/photo.jpg",
 "gender": "male",
 "locale": "en"
}
```

The `id` field here is also unique and has the bonus of being used across Google services.